# Pixelated PDF in Apple Preview slideshow mode, but not in regular window

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, slideshow, anti-aliasing

I have a PDF which is a presentation exported from OpenOffice.  Two of the slides in this presentation have embedded .eps graphs.  When I run the presentation using Preview's slideshow mode, the graphs are severely aliased and the axes are illegible.  But when I just view the PDF in regular windowed mode, the graphs are properly antialiased and legible.

Is there any way to get Preview to do the same display that it does in windowed mode, but in fullscreen (no window title, no menu bar)?

(I don't want to just run the presentation from OpenOffice, because OpenOffice shows the same horrible aliasing effects plus it takes about 30 seconds to show the slide.  I don't have, and don't want, Acrobat or MS Office.  However, please do feel free to suggest other programs for doing PDF-based slideshows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/)'s presentation mode displayed my graphs correctly.